# Tactile keypad for nexus 5

Tags: keyboard, nexus-5

I've got a new nexus 5 & I know it sounds odd but I just can't seem to find the option to switch to phonepad type keyboard for texting. Could someone please help me with it?

**edit**

I'm looking for a keypad like this to use for texting.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is a good choice to use a alphanumeric keyboard instead of a qwerty one.

But here is some choices for you:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=bigkeyboard.bordeux.net
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bb.keyboard.wf

This one is paid, but seems better:

play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.fredricknet.inputmethod.latin

There is no much people making this keyboards, so it is probability that the keyboard is no longer updated.

Comment: Big keyboard (the first link) would have exactly been what I wanted if it used a dictionary. Would you know of a free version of one similar to the paid one?

Comment: @mindReader Well, I did not find other good keyboards, the ones that I wrote were the best I could find.